# Changing the sender address to default server in Outlook Object Mail

Tags: c#, outlook

I have the following code to send emails automatically when looping through data retrieved from db:

```
public void sendMailV2(string subject, string body, string emailAddress)
  {
        // Create the Outlook application.
        Outlook.Application  oApp = new Outlook.Application();

        // Get the NameSpace and Logon information.
        Outlook.NameSpace oNS = oApp.GetNamespace("mapi");

        // Log on by using a dialog box to choose the profile.
        oNS.Logon(Missing.Value, Missing.Value, true, true); 

        // Alternate logon method that uses a specific profile.
        // TODO: If you use this logon method, 
        //  change the profile name to an appropriate value.
        //oNS.Logon("YourValidProfile", Missing.Value, false, true); 

        // Create a new mail item.
        Outlook.MailItem oMsg = (Outlook.MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

        // Set the subject.
        oMsg.Subject = subject;

        // Set HTMLBody.
        oMsg.HTMLBody = body;

        // Add a recipient.
        Outlook.Recipients oRecips = (Outlook.Recipients)oMsg.Recipients;
        // TODO: Change the recipient in the next line if necessary.
        Outlook.Recipient oRecip = (Outlook.Recipient)oRecips.Add(emailAddress);
        oRecip.Resolve();

        // Send.
        oMsg.Send();

        // Log off.
        oNS.Logoff();

        // Clean up.
        oRecip = null;
        oRecips = null;
        oMsg = null;
        oNS = null;
        oApp = null;
    }
```

However, I want the emails to be sent from the server, not my own outlook. I have the username and password for the server(someserver@serving.com) but I can't figure out how and where to implement them.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is no need to create a new Application instance if you need to send multiple emails. You may consider moving the following lines of code outside of the method and create the Application instance at the global scope.

```
    // Create the Outlook application.
    Outlook.Application  oApp = new Outlook.Application();
```

If you have got another accounts configured in Outlook, you can use the [SendUsingAccount](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869311(v=office.15).aspx) property of the MailItem class which allows to set an Account object that represents the account under which the MailItem is to be sent.

If you don't have the required account configured in Outlook you may consider using the BCL classes for getting the job done. See [How to send email from C#](http://csharp.net-informations.com/communications/csharp-smtp-mail.htm) for more information.